# How can I add a "tag"-system to my account-system

Tags: c++, database, architecture, mariadb, accountmanager

I'm trying to create Account-/Usersystem. My Problem is, I need a system that handles multiple users with the same username (each on has a specific id), but the users must can login!

So... I think a "tag" system like that from Discord is nice. A four digit number, so that the user can login as "Max#1234". Great! But the problem is, how can I create them?

I'm using MariaDB as my database. A user can be created with the REST API which I have written in C++ (Linux) with the C++-REST-SDK (Casablanca).

Has anyone an idea how I handle this "tags".

Comment: On your database you can have an ID that you increment on each registration and use it as the number, being the first one #0001. To allow users to have the same username you'd simply not assign it as being `unique`. Edit: Your primary key would be the ID, obviously.

Comment: As i said, i have such like this. In my table there is a parameter id, but this is a int64 (snowflake) but no users wants to know all this digits! And with auto-increment, it counts up, for every user.. so that i have users lik this:

Max#0001
Max#0002
Noob#0003 (<- not wanted! It must be Noob#0001, as example)

Comment: Oh I get it. You can add a tag_id to your table and before you insert you can query how many users have that name and set the tag_id as that number + 1.

Comment: Yes i can do that, but i think there where two problems:
1. when you have a very creative name that realy no one has, then you have the tag 0000 or 0001 -> than as a player you know, oh this name already exists (for example) 200 times! I have a such bad name :-(
2. Doesn't this take a lot of performance?

Comment: I don't understand what you really want. Edit: Yes, it may take a hit on performance if you have a big database.

Comment: The mainly thing i want, is an Accountsystem, that handles the same username multiple times, and the user must can login by typing his name, a hashtag and his four digit number!

Comment: So, you want a four digit number that can't be fully sequential (auto-increment) and can't be partially sequential (auto-increment by username)? Then I don't know how to help you. Best solution is to clear up what you want or just go for a random number you haven't used on that username.